# mdl-menu list not opening if its id is set dynamically via data binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, data-binding, material-design-lite

I am using **knockoutJS** for data binding. I am looping through a list of comments and using mdl-menu for each comment to provide admin options on comment like edit and delete and also setting each comment's menu icon's id according to corresponding comment id. So **id** for 1st comment will be "**comment-1**" and **'for' attribute** in mdl menu list will be "comment-1". On clicking the menu icon, I am using **componentHandler.upgradeDom()** to register the elements again, but still the menu is not opening.

Comment: We need more information (error message, code sample, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I made an attempt at it using a binding handler. click the menu icon to see the menu. click the add button to add a new menu item.

you can run below, or if you want to modify it in jsfiddle it is here https://jsfiddle.net/7zop2n9j/7/

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.mdmemenu = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    var source = allBindings.get('menuOptions');
    var sourceUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(source);
    var myId = valueAccessor()();
    var myHtml = '<button id = "'
    myHtml = myHtml + myId;
    myHtml = myHtml + '"'
    myHtml = myHtml + 'class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">';
    myHtml = myHtml + ' <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>'
    myHtml = myHtml + '</button>'
    myHtml = myHtml + ' <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"'
    myHtml = myHtml + 'for = "'
    myHtml = myHtml + myId;
    myHtml = myHtml + '"'

    myHtml = myHtml + '</ul>'
    $(element).append(myHtml);
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor);
    $(element).empty();
    var source = allBindings.get('menuOptions');
    var sourceUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(source);
    var myId = valueAccessor()();
    var myHtml = '<button id = "'
    myHtml = myHtml + myId;
    myHtml = myHtml + '"'
    myHtml = myHtml + 'class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">';
    myHtml = myHtml + ' <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>'
    myHtml = myHtml + '</button>'
    myHtml = myHtml + ' <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"'
    myHtml = myHtml + 'for = "'
    myHtml = myHtml + myId;
    myHtml = myHtml + '"'
    $.each(sourceUnwrapped, function(i, item) {
      myHtml = myHtml + '<li class="mdl-menu__item">' + item.myText() + '</li>'
    });
    myHtml = myHtml + '</ul>'
    $(element).append(myHtml);
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  }
};

function menuOption(myText) {
  var self = this;
  this.myText = ko.observable(myText);
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.menuOptions = ko.observableArray()
  this.myId = ko.observable('demo-menu-lower-left');
  this.addRow = function() {
    self.menuOptions.push(new menuOption('new menu item'));
  }

}

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
  myViewModel.menuOptions.push(new menuOption('Some Action'));
  myViewModel.menuOptions.push(new menuOption('Another Action'));
  myViewModel.menuOptions.push(new menuOption('Disabled Action'));
  myViewModel.menuOptions.push(new menuOption('Yet Another Action'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="mdmemenu: myId, menuOptions: menuOptions "></div>

<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
  <i class="material-icons" data-bind="click:addRow">add</i> 
</button>
```